# How to redirect output from RD batch command (without /S /Q)

Tags: batch-file

The following folder delete command output is not being redirected into a file as expected:

```
RD folder >> logfile.txt
```

This only works when the folder AND all sub-folders and files are deleted using:

```
RD folder /S /Q >> logfile.txt
```

However, the intention is to delete only an empty folder, not any files, and redirect all output into a file (error messages and all).

How can this be done?

The full batch file context is to delete all empty folders in a user profile backup as follows:

```
set Root=e:\users\somebody
for %%A in (Desktop Documents Downloads Favorites Install Music OneDrive Pictures Videos) do (
    if exist "%Root%\%%A\" (
        echo %%A ------- >> Backuplog.txt
        for /F "tokens=*" %%B in ('dir %Root%\%%A /ad /b /s ^| sort /r') do rd %%B >> Backuplog.txt
    )
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rd` produces no output when deleteing an empty folder, so this result is expected. However, you can use the conditional operators `&&` (previous command succeeded) and `||` (previous comand failed). So it may be

```
set "Root=e:\users\somebody"
for %%A in (Desktop Documents Downloads Favorites Install Music OneDrive Pictures Videos) do (
    if exist "%Root%\%%A\" (
        echo %%A ------- >> Backuplog.txt
        for /F "tokens=*" %%B in ('dir %Root%\%%A /ad /b /s ^| sort /r') do rd "%%B" 2>NUL && (>>Backuplog.txt echo succesful) || (>>Backuplog.txt %%B echo failed) 
    )
)
```